# Visual Studio only errors. Here's my project

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Visual Studio is giving me a really, REALLY bad headache. The code compiles just fine on Codelite, OS X Terminal, Xcode and so on but Visual Studio C++ 2010 and using a .c source file, it's being a.... harlot. I have to make this code working on Visual Studio as it is my main priority. I have no idea why it doesn't work. No, I am not asking you to write the code for me because as I said it's working fine and dandy using anything other than Visual Studio. What I want to know is why isn't it working on VS C++ 2010?

Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void list(); //This function prompts has the visual necessities to prompt the user to select what to do.
int max_age(int a[],int size); //This function uses a for loop statement to search the index and find the biggest value.
int min_age (int a[], int size); //This function uses the exact same method as the one above but to look for the minimum value instead.
float average (int a[], int size); //This function calculates the average age within the sample collected, a.k.a the array
float standardDeviation (int a[], int size); //By using the given calculation in the PDF, this function is sued to calculate the standard deviation.


int main()
{ //A switch statement is used because it is much more natural (for me) to code it.
    int array[30] = {55, 43, 22, 10, 5, 1, 88, 91, 76, 68, 51, 35, 31, 15, 18, 21, 22, 33, 4, 28, 28, 77, 71, 44, 48, 51, 27, 28, 6, 36};
    int input=0;
    do{
        list();
        scanf("%d",&input);
        switch(input){
            case 1:
                printf("The Mean is: %f\n",average(array,30));
                break;
        case 2:
            printf("Maximum age is: %d\n", max_age(array,30));
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Minimum age is: %d\n", min_age(array,30));
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Standard Deviation is: %f\n", standardDeviation(array,30));
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("**TERMINATED**\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please enter the correct input[1-5]\n");
    }
 }while(input!=5);
 return 0;
 }


float average(int a[],int size)
{
//This function sums the array and then devides it by 30.0 to find the average age.
int sum=0;
int i;
for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
{
    sum+=a[i];
}
return (sum/30.0);
}


void list()
    {
    printf("Please choose an option\n");
    printf("\t\t 1. Calculate mean value\n");
    printf("\t\t 2. Calculate maximum age\n");
    printf("\t\t 3. Calculate minimum age\n");
    printf("\t\t 4. Calculate Standard Deviation \n");
    printf("\t\t 5. EXIT\n\n\n\t\t");
    return;
    }

int max_age (int a[],int size)
    { //This function is used to find the max age by using a for loop statement that will keep incrementing until the array finishes and we find the max age, where the variable maximum_age will continue to redefine itself until it finds the absolute maximum age given within the array.
        int i;
        int maximum_age= a[0];
        for (i=0; i<size; i++)
            {
                if(a[i]>maximum_age)
                maximum_age = a[i];
    }

        return maximum_age;
}

int min_age (int a[],int size)
{
//To calculate the minimum age, I have used a for loop statement that continues to increment until it finds the absolute minimum value within the given array which is a[i].

    int i;
    int minimum_age= a[0];
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<minimum_age)
        minimum_age = a[i];
    }

    return minimum_age;
}

float standardDeviation(int a[],int size)
{
    int i;
    float up=0.0;
    float mean = average(a,size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        up = up + pow(a[i]-mean,2);
    }
float result = sqrt(up/(size-1));
return (result);
}
```

Here's my errors on visual studio, keep in mind that I get the same error for the entire error list.

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

Comment: Ok, and on what line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also, cannot reproduce it using VS2013..

Comment: Line 49, 50, 101,102,105,106. Where it says the error code I posted above :/. This is getting seriously frustrating.

Comment: i just copy/pasted ur whole src into a vs2010sp1 instance and it compiled and run out of the box. Did you "#define for" somewhere or something that like?

Comment: I can't reproduce it using VS2010 express.

Comment: Try using C++ compiler and naming your source file as source.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that MS VS 2010 does not support C99, So all declarations shall be in the beginning of code block.

For example

```
float standardDeviation(int a[],int size)
{
    int i;
    float up=0.0;
    float mean = average(a,size);
    float result;

    //...

    result = sqrt(up/(size-1));
    return (result);
}
```

Constructions like this

```
for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
```

are also wrong. You may not use declarations in loops.

Take into account that you already defined i for example in function `average`. So you can use this variable instead of declared variable in the loop

```
float average(int a[],int size)
{
//This function sums the array and then devides it by 30.0 to find the average age.
int sum=0;
int i;
for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
```

Comment: the c++ tag should really be removed from the question then

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved the solution by removing the declarations from the loops, also, I removed the "result" variable and just returned the argument which made it work all together.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vlad, I was able to solve the problem by removing the declarations from the for loops and removing the result variable and returned the argument instead.

Here's an example of what I fixed.

```
float standardDeviation(int a[],int size){
int i;
float up=0.0;
float mean = average(a,size);
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) // removed the declaration from here
{
    up = up + pow(a[i]-mean,2);
}

return (sqrt(up/(size-1))); //instead of returning a variable, I am returning the argument instead.
}
```